# For simple $\mathbb C[G]$-modules is the representation unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $R$ be a ring, a $R$-module is called simple if it has no proper, nontrivial submodules. Let $G$ be a finite group, and denote by $\mathbb C[G]$ the free vector space over $G$, with the product given by multiplying the basis vectors according to the multiplication in $G$ and extending lineary. Alternatively this set could be thought of as the set of functions $G \to \mathbb C$ with the convolution product
$$
 (f \ast h)(x) = \sum_{y,z \in G, yz = x} f(y)h(z) = \sum_{y\in G} f(y)h(y^{-1}x).
$$
Then $\mathbb C[G]$ is a ring. If $M$ is a module over $\mathbb C[G]$ which is simple, then $M$ is also a vector space over $\mathbb C \subseteq \mathbb C[G]$. Does the simplicity of $M$ as a $\mathbb C[G]$-module implies there is just one unique representation $\pi : G \to GL(V)$ (a representation is a homomorphism $G \to GL(V)$)?

As $\pi(g)v := g\cdot v$ (where as $G \subseteq \mathbb C[G]$ the product $g \cdot v$ is meant to be in the module) is one representation, this would be then the only one.

Comment: No, it just means that the $\pi$ you get is a simple representation. There can be multiple irreducible representations. For example, if $G$ is a abelian, there are many  one-dimensional $G$-modules, all irreducible.

Comment: I mean for a **fixed** $G$-module is there just one representation from $G$ to the module regarded as a vector space over $\mathbb C$, that there could be many simple $G$-modules is clear to me.

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean by that. The module regarded as a vector space is just a vector space, and there are lots of representations of $G$ in that vector space. You seems to want an additional unstated condition that I'm missing.

Comment: This question is related to another question of mine. There I do not understand if the representation is not unique how we could derive the stated sum for the character as posted in my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476152/character-representation-of-right-regular-representation-as-sum-of-irreducible-c

Comment: If one has to read another question to understand this question, put the link in this question. As stated now, the question is missing context to allow anybody to provide you an answer. Help people help you.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $V$ is any finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}G$ module (I don't need to assume irreducible). Given any basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ I can write
$$g.v_j=\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}(g)v_i \;\;\;(j=1,\ldots,n)$$
for some scalars $a_{ij}(g)$. The assignment $\pi:G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$, $g\mapsto (a_{ij}(g))_{i,j=1}^n$, defines a representation of $G$ and every representation can be obtained in this way.

The degree of freedom one has to define such a representation is a choice of basis. In particular, if $\pi,\pi':G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ are representations of the same $G$-module $V$, then there exists an invertible linear transformation $\phi:V\to V$ such that
$$\phi\pi(g)=\pi'(g)\phi\;\;\;\mbox{for all }g\in G.$$
In other words, $\pi'(g)=\phi\pi(g)\phi^{-1}$ are conjugate matrices for every $g\in G$.

**Added:** Based on you're comment, there seems to be a need for a review of some linear algebra. Let's say $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ is another basis and
$$g.w_j=\sum_ib_{ij}(g)w_i$$
so that $\pi'(g)=(b_{ij}(g))_{ij}$ is the corresponding representation. Since $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_i\}$ are two bases, we can write
$$v_j=\sum_{k}c_{kj}w_k$$
for some invertible matrix $(c_{ij})_{i,j}$. Then, at the level of $\mathbb{C}G$-modules, we have
\begin{align*}
g.v_j&=g.\left(\sum_k c_{kj}w_k\right)\\
&=\sum_{i,k}b_{ik}(g)c_{kj}w_i
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
g.v_j&=\sum_ka_{kj}(g)v_k\\
&=\sum_ka_{kj}(g)v_k=\sum_{i,k}c_{ik}a_{kj}(g)w_i
\end{align*}
Therefore, taking the difference,
$$0=\sum_i\left(\sum_k(b_{ik}(g)c_{kj}-c_{ik}a_{kj}(g))\right)w_i$$
Now, using the fact that $\{w_i\}$ is a basis, we have 
$$\sum_{k}c_{ik}a_{kj}(g)=\sum_{k}b_{ik}(g)c_{kj}$$
for all $i,j$.

Let $\phi:V\to V$ be the invertible linear transformation $\phi(v_i)=\sum_kc_{ki}w_k$. Then, the computation above shows that on the level of representations $\phi\pi(g)=\pi'(g)\phi$ as stated above.

Comment: "every repr. can be obtained in this way." - you mean every repr. compatible with the $G$-module, i.e such that $g\cdot v = \pi(g)v$? But the existence of $\phi$ is not clear to me? If $\pi, \pi' : G \to GL(V)$ are representations compatible with the same module $V$, then after choosing some basis $\{ v_i \}$ we would have $\pi(g)v_j = \sum_i a_{ij}(g) v_i, \pi'(g) v_j = \sum_i b_{ij}(g) v_i$, and the compatibility condition with the $G$-module would force $gv_i= \pi(g)v_i = \pi'(g) v_i$, but I do not see this implies $CA(g) = B(g)C$ for one $C$ and all $g$ & $A(g)=(a_{ij}(g)), B=(b_{ij}(g))$?

Comment: @Stefan Please see my edit above. As I have already explained, every representation of $G$ is obtained from a $G$-module by choosing a basis. I have spelled out the effect of changing the basis for you. You seem to be thinking "every $G$-module is obtained from a representation". This is backward. Instead: Every representation is obtained from a $G$-module.

Comment: Guess I understand, but let me also note that regarding my previous comment, that $\pi(g)v_i = \pi'(g)v_i$ implies $\pi(g) = \pi'(g)$ as linear maps. But regardig "every $G$-module is obtained from a representation", that is exactly what is said in Proposition 2.3.2 (i.e. given a $G$-module we can find a representation inducing this module) in these notes: http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/group/gind2_3.html Would be great if you take a look and maybe glarify why thinking "every $G$-module is obtained from a representation" is a misconception if I think wrongly about this Proposition...

Comment: @Stefan In your comment above: ``given a G-module we can find a representation inducing this module'' Note: one starts with a $G$ module, then finds a representation, not the other way around. This is precisely what is said in Proposition 2.3.2 of Dan Bump's notes and its proof is exactly what I have posted above. I hope this helps.

Comment: But directly above the Proposition he does exactly that, to cite: "If $(\pi, V)$ is a representation, then we may define a multiplication $\mathbb C[G] \times V \to V$ by $$ f \cdot v := \sum_{g\in G} f(g)\pi(g)v." $$ So here the representation is first, and then comes the $G$-module. Is this just a theoretical remark, not used in practice?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I believe this is just theoretical. As Dan says in his notes, modules and representations are really the same thing (in the same way that group actions are the same thing as homomorphisms into symmetric groups), but practically speaking, modules are easier to come by, and you then get a representation by choosing a basis. In this sense, I feel that modules are more primary.

Comment: Okay, guess I got it now. But regarding your analogy (which is good), in the module vs. representation analogy we extend the "action" given by the representation to an action of the free vector space over $G$ on $V$, is this to exploit the additional linear structure we have by the action (as $GL(V) \le Aut(V)$, not just $Sym(V)$)? In the simple group action vs. homomorphism case we do not consider the free vector space over $G$, which would not make any sense at all as we have no addtion on the set acted on.So in the module case we can "pull back" algebraic relations in $V$ to ones in $C[G]$?

Comment: @Stefan From an action of $G$ on a set $X$, we can get a module by letting $G$ act on a vector space with basis $X$. Now, as far as $G$- vs $\mathbb{C}G$-modules goes, they are the same thing (either extend a $G$-module linearly or restrict a $\mathbb{C}G$-module to $G\subset\mathbb{C}G$). The reason I prefer $\mathbb{C}G$ is that it allows one to use all the tools from ring theory (e.g. Wedderburn-Artin). Also, as you point out, $\mathbb{C}G$ is a linear space, which is nice.